# Using docker as agent in jenkins pipeline yields to a docker command not found

Tags: jenkins

Why is it that docker not found when i use docker as an agent in jenkins pipeline?

```
+ docker inspect -f . node:7-alpine
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/poobao-aws-services@tmp/durable- 
13f890b0/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/project- 
name@tmp/durable-13f890b0/script.sh: docker: not found
```

In Global Tools Configuration, I have docker as automatically install.

Answer (score 1):

I have docker set to install automatically as follows, with a declarative pipeline as follows...

[image: Docker Install]

My jenkinsfile then has this initialization stage (amended from [here](https://automatingguy.com/2017/11/06/jenkins-pipelines-simple-delivery-flow/))

```
stage('Install dependencies') {
  steps {
    script {
      def dockerTool = tool name: 'docker', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
      withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}/bin"]) {
          //stages
          //here we can trigger: sh "sudo ${DOCKER}/docker ..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When built it then installs automatically...

[image]