Jenkins Agent: docker not found
I've been following the official Jenkins documentation to create a multi-container setup where a Docker daemon container supports a Jenkins container and a separate Jenkins agent container.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/

This is the docker-compose used
services:
  jenkins-docker:
    image: docker:dind
    container_name: jenkins-docker
    privileged: true
    networks:
      jenkins: 
        aliases: 
          - docker
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs
    volumes:
      - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "5000:5000"
      - "2376:2376"
    command: --storage-driver overlay2

  jenkins-master:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.jenkins-master
    image: jenkins-dockerized
    container_name: jenkins-master
    networks:
      jenkins: 
        aliases: 
          - jenkins
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
    volumes:
      - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
          - jenkins-docker

  jenkins-agent-1:
      image: jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17
      container_name: jenkins-agent-1
      networks:
        jenkins: 
          aliases: 
            - agent-1
      ports:
        - "4444:22"
      environment:
        - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=${JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY}
      depends_on:
        - jenkins-master

networks:
  jenkins:
    name: jenkins

volumes:
  jenkins-docker-certs:
    name: jenkins-docker-certs
  jenkins-home:
    name: jenkins-home
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
docker-compose
      device: ../jenkins_home
      o: bind


PROBLEM
When using Jenkins' built-in agent to execute pipelines containing Docker commands, everything works as expected. However, when using the external agent jenkins-agent-1 to execute the same pipelines, I get the error docker: not found.
Pipelines that do not use Docker commands execute successfully on the external agent.
This is the Dockerfile.jenkins-master that I used to create the 'jenkins-master' container
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.479.2-jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "docker-workflow:580.vc0c340686b_54 json-path-api"

UPDATE
I've installed the Docker client on the agent, but the image is 555MB, which is quite large. Using Alpine instead of Debian would definitely have made it smaller, but I couldn't get it to work.
Here's the Dockerfile I used
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent:debian-jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release curl
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli


Hi, this question has been asked at least twice on thus forum already. Did you consider using the search function above?

Can you show them to me? I've been looking for them, and I'd have saved time if I knew.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jenkins+agent+docker+not+found , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222092/is-it-possible-to-install-and-run-docker-inside-node-container-in-jenkins , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770546/using-docker-as-agent-in-jenkins-pipeline-yields-to-a-docker-command-not-found https://medium.com/@haroldfinch01/docker-in-docker-jenkins-agent-46014bfd3a03 https://medium.com/@yann.cardaillac/dockerized-jenkins-dind-c923774893dc

The jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17 image isn't packaged with the docker binary and it has no access to the docker daemon.
You can copy the docker binary into the agent image e.g.:
FROM docker.io/library/docker:27.4.1-cli AS cli
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17
COPY --from=cli /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker

... and connect to the docker daemon using TCP or the unix socket e.g.:


You can copy the docker binary into the agent image and hope to be really lucky and that nothing breaks. This is severally bad practice and shouldn't be done. Instead, you should install docker into the image using the package manager native to the image. Also, i think there are ready to use Jenkins afent with docker - kindly please check docker hub.

@KamilCuk docker.io/library/docker:27.4.1-cli is built FROM alpine:3.21, the jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine-jdk17 image is built from ADD alpine-minirootfs-3.21.0-x86_64.tar.gz. It's not terrible practice as long as you know what you're doing.
